# Large dynamic array Fortran declaration-seg fault

Tags: arrays, dynamic, fortran

i wish to use dynamic declaration for a large array in fortran95 with allocate(matrix(size)),while size=10^7 and the content real*8 numbers.If size<13*10^6 everything runs smoothly without any error, but if size>13*10^6 then i get a segmentation fault on the run. It is important that I use dynamic declaration since the size of the array is calculated within the program. I use Mac OSX 64bit and gfortran 4.6.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10**7 elements of real*8 is 76 MiB, so should pose no problem (I have successfully allocated several GiB arrays with GFortran, though I don't use OSX). Can you post a self-contained example in order to further analyze your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using an array of size 10**8.  It worked for me with Mac OS X and gfortran 4.6.   Does it work on your computer?

```
program test_lrg

   integer, parameter :: DoubleReal_K = selected_real_kind (14)
   integer, parameter :: QuadReal_K = selected_real_kind (32)
   integer, parameter :: RegularInt_K = selected_int_kind (8)
   integer, parameter :: VeryLongInt_K = selected_int_kind (18)

   real (DoubleReal_K), dimension (:), allocatable :: array
   integer (RegularInt_K) :: i
   integer (RegularInt_K), parameter :: N = 100000000_RegularInt_K
   real (QuadReal_K) :: sum
   integer (VeryLongInt_K) :: CalcSum

   allocate (array (N))

   do i=1, N
      array (i) = i
   end do

   do i=1, N
      sum = sum + array (i)
   end do
   write (*, *) sum

   CalcSum = N
   CalcSum = ( CalcSum * (CalcSum + 1_VeryLongInt_K) ) / 2_VeryLongInt_K
   write (*, *) CalcSum

   stop

end program test_lrg
```

Try compiling with debugging options, such as:

```
-fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=bounds  -fcheck=do  -fcheck=mem  -fcheck=recursion  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace
```

Comment: thanks both of you!I figured out the problem!It was an error actually caused by MPI(i'm programming for parallel implementation) and not by the allocation itself!Thanks again!